# VBA code for nested dictionaries in class objects

Tags: vba, class, object, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to use a class object to store variable data in a dictionary (also in the class object). The dictionary has sub dictionaries to store nested data from the class object. The values in my dictionary keeps getting overwritten as I load new data. Please assist.

Here is the main program:

```
Sub TReeTestShort()
Dim RootVar As cTree
Dim ClassLoader As cTree
Dim Key As Variant

Set RootVar = New cTree
RootVar.InitDictOnly
With RootVar
    Set ClassLoader = New cTree
    .Dict.Add 1, ClassLoader.InitBranch("2008/02/02")
    .Dict.Add 2, ClassLoader.InitBranch("2008/03/03")
    .Dict.Add 3, ClassLoader.InitBranch("2008/04/04")
    Debug.Print RootVar.Dict(1).Branch ' Prints 2008/04/04 instead of 2008/02/02
    With RootVar.Dict(1)
        Set ClassLoader = New cTree
        .Dict.Add 1, ClassLoader.InitLeave("SOL")
        Debug.Print .Dict(1).Leave
            With RootVar.Dict(1).Dict(1)
                Set ClassLoader = New cTree
                .Dict.Add 1, ClassLoader.InitBranch("EY50")
                Debug.Print .Dict(1).Branch
            End With
    End With
End With

For Each Key In RootVar.Dict()
    Debug.Print RootVar.Dict(Key).Branch
Next Key

End Sub
```

Here is the class object (called cTree)

```
Option Explicit

Private pBranch         As String
Private pLeave          As String
Private pChildren       As Collection
Private pDict           As Dictionary

Public Property Get Branch() As String
    Branch = pBranch
End Property

Public Property Get Leave() As String
    Leave = pLeave
End Property

Public Property Get Children() As Collection
    Set Children = pChildren
End Property

Public Property Get Dict() As Dictionary
    Set Dict = pDict
End Property

Public Property Let Branch(BValue As String)
    pBranch = BValue
End Property

Public Function Init(BValue As String, LValue As String) As cTree
    pLeave = LValue
    pBranch = BValue
    Set pChildren = New Collection
    Set Init = Me
End Function

Public Function InitDictOnly() As cTree
    Set pDict = New Dictionary
    Set InitDictOnly = Me
End Function

Public Function InitBranch(BValue As String) As cTree
    pBranch = BValue
    Set pDict = New Dictionary
    Set InitBranch = Me
End Function

Public Function InitLeave(LValue As String) As cTree
    pLeave = LValue
    Set pDict = New Dictionary
    Set InitLeave = Me
End Function
```

Comment: where is cTree? I think it is likely the problem is in cTree.

Comment: @Don - I attached the wrong class object. Here is cTree:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your class object before using it to load new dictionary items by adding:

```
Set ClassLoader = New cTree
```

before each

```
.Dict.Add 1, ClassLoader.InitBranch("2008/02/02")
```

Below is the updated sub:

```
Sub TReeTestShort()
    Dim RootVar As cTree2
    Dim ClassLoader As cTree2
    Dim Key As Variant

    Set RootVar = New cTree2
    With RootVar
        .Init "", ""

        Set ClassLoader = New cTree2
        .Dict.Add "key1", ClassLoader.Init("2008/02/02", "")

        Set ClassLoader = New cTree2
        .Dict.Add "key2", ClassLoader.Init("2008/03/03", "")

        Set ClassLoader = New cTree2
        .Dict.Add "key3", ClassLoader.Init("2008/04/04", "")

        For Each Key In RootVar.Dict()
            Debug.Print RootVar.Dict.Item(Key).Branch
        Next Key

        Set ClassLoader = New cTree2
        .Dict("key1").Dict.Add "key1.1", ClassLoader.Init("", "SOL")
        Debug.Print RootVar.Dict("key1").Dict.Item("key1.1").Leave

        Set ClassLoader = New cTree2
        .Dict("key1").Dict("key1.1").Dict.Add "key1.1.1", ClassLoader.Init("EY50", "")
        Debug.Print RootVar.Dict("key1").Dict("key1.1").Dict("key1.1.1").Branch
    End With

End Sub
```

Below is the updated Class Object (called cTree2)

```
Option Explicit

Private pBranch         As String
Private pLeave          As String
Private pDict           As Dictionary

Public Property Get Branch() As String
    Branch = pBranch
End Property

Public Property Get Leave() As String
    Leave = pLeave
End Property

Public Property Get Dict() As Dictionary
    Set Dict = pDict
End Property

Public Function Init(BValue As String, LValue As String) As cTree2
    pLeave = LValue
    pBranch = BValue
    Set pDict = New Dictionary
    Set Init = Me
End Function
```